# How to draw and show map in in ArcGIS C# Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, arcgis, silverlight-5.0, arcgis-runtime-net

I recently need to develop a ArcGIS system in Silverlight C# Application via visual studio community 2022. The main problem I meet now is to set the GraphicsLayer in map, and show the map in the layout. And since silverlight is no more support by ArcGIS, therefore, there is hard to find a good instructions for developing ArcGIS in C# silverlight application.
The code snippet is as below:

```
MainPage.xaml:
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication20230823.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" 
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
    xmlns:Anno="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/extensions/annotations/2008"               
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <esri:SimpleLineSymbol x:Key="SLineSymbol" Color="black" Width="1" />
        <esri:SimpleFillSymbol x:Key="DrawFillSymbol" Fill="#4C12EEEE" BorderBrush="#FF04F0FB" BorderThickness="2" />
        <esri:Map Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Key="MapMain" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" WrapAround="True">
         <esri:Map.Extent >
             <esri:Envelope XMin="278000" YMin="272000" XMax="353000" YMax="2790000">
                 <esri:Envelope.SpatialReference>
                     <esri:SpatialReference WKID="102443"/>
                 </esri:Envelope.SpatialReference>
             </esri:Envelope>
         </esri:Map.Extent>
         <esri:GraphicsLayer ID="MDraw">
         </esri:GraphicsLayer>
        </esri:Map>
    </Grid.Resources>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the .cs file is as following:

```
MainPage.xaml.cs
    private Draw MDrawObject;
    private Map MapMain = new Map();
    public MainPage()
    {
        MapMain = LayoutRoot.Resources["MapMain"] as Map;
        MapMain.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        MapMain.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        MapMain.WrapAround = true;
        MapMain.SnapToLevels = true;
        MapMain.MinimumResolution = 0.235185;
        MapMain.MaximumResolution = 264.584;
        MapMain.Height = 318;
        MapMain.Width = 483;

        ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer glayer;
        glayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer()
        {
            Url ="..../TCBaseMap/Land_500/MapServer",
            ID = "FDiagram",
            Visible = true
        };
        Map1.Layers.Insert(0, glayer);

        MDrawObject = new Draw(MapMain)
        {
          FillSymbol = LayoutRoot.Resources["DrawFillSymbol"] as FillSymbol,
          LineSymbol = LayoutRoot.Resources["SLineSymbol"] as LineSymbol,
          DrawMode = DrawMode.Rectangle
        };
    }
```

Since the class of ESRI.ArcGIS.Client is used in .cs, and in .xaml, the map is defined
in <Grid.Resources>, so there is no declaration and binding for map's location to layout,
so after compile, the system doesn't show any map layer in screen, but other silverlight components are well shown.
How to make the map can be shown through the code in MainPage.xaml.cs? Any instruction is
highly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to put UI controls like the Map control in resources - that's supposed to be in the layout itself.

Having said that, you do realize that the Silverlight plugin has been out of support for a while now, and the ArcGIS Silverlight component has been out of support for quite a few years now. You should not be starting new projects on Silverlight. If you want to build web apps, use the ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript, or if you're looking for mobile/desktop apps, look at the ArcGIS Maps SDK for .NET (which is an evolution of the older ArcGIS Silverlight SDK)